# Windows Core Audio API GUID's

Tags: api, windows-7, audio, windows-vista, guid

I'm using an implementation of the Windows Core Audio API, specifically the IMMDevice interface, the code for which can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130303044133/http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx).  My goal in using this code is to pull the friendly name of a particular sound device.

The code appears to implement such functionality, however the property for the friendly name really appears to be returning what the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370812(v=VS.85).aspx) refers to as the "Device Description".  Drilling down into the code takes me to a PKEY class that defines a GUID.  The GUID, based on simply looking at the code and MSDN documentation, appears to be a predefined value that the OS recognizes to represent a property in the property store for that device.  So, my assumption at this point is that the original programmer intended to define the friendly name property, but provided the GUID for device description by mistake.  I'd like to extend/correct this API to provide both the device description **and** the friendly name.

Here is where I run into trouble.  I cannot find any sort of reference for these GUID's.  I've pored over all the documentation I could find and simply cannot locate any such reference.  I'm looking for someone to tell me my assumption about these GUID's is wrong and set me on the right track, or if it is correct to point me to a reference to them.  I'm sure I've missed useful and critical details, so if more info is needed just let me know and I'll provide what I can.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should clarify this to head off some responses I just anticipated.  I'm using the API for lots of other things that are working well, the friendly name functionality is to simply make my life easier as I'm doing them.  So, I really cannot entertain suggestions regarding alternate audio interface options (other API's, .NET libraries etc).